# Pause Resume Client-Server File Upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket

I know it's possible if you used java/flash/C type programming.. 
but, Is there any way to pause or resume during uploading or resume broken upload using php or javascript or jquery on that matter? maybe php socket function?

Comment: Do you understand that PHP runs on the server? It's not clear from the phrasing of your question.

Comment: -1 for using "u" instead of "you"

Comment: @Cameron yes I know about PHP runs on the server, although still a bit confused with client-server technology type. so how about using jquery/javascript? these are runs on client.

Comment: You are unlikely to get a cross-browser solution for this using only JS/jQuery. However, if cross-browser is not an issue, then you might want to look at HTML WebSockets and HTML5 File Access features. I guess you should be able to use the 2 in combo to get what you are looking for: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/

Comment: @user: The way a file is uploaded is over HTTP, which is a protocol running on top of a TCP connection, which is what actually carries the packets of bytes. In order to pause an upload, you'd need to tell the client to temporarily stop sending bytes (while keeping the TCP connection alive). There's no interface to do this with regular file uploads, but it might be be possible with web sockets. Basically, you're asking to do a very low-level operation from a high-level interface.

Comment: @technofoobar: As I understand it, currently you can only send ASCII data with WebSockets, so you'd have to base64-encode binary files, which is gonna be really inefficient for large binary files.

Comment: (psst, all your recent deletions might trigger the automatic question ban)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/jQuery have ZERO control over the browser's built-in file transfer works. You'd need to use a plug-in to change how the browser itself works.

Comment: is not true anymore ...  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-example-slicingfiles

Comment: Even more so with Fetch + ReadableStream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do 'resumable' uploads with only Javascript on client side.

demo: http://dnduploader.filkor.org/